# Reading single BLOB entry from stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I need to complete my task using only stored procedures.

In my app I have Models called 'Document' and 'DocumentInfo' which refers to mysql tables. For example I got simplest stored procedure to get list of documentInfos by Filename:

SQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `GetDocumentByName` (DocName varchar(255))
BEGIN
Select * from GetAllDocuments where DocumentName like DocName;
END$$
```

C#:

```
public List<DocumentsInfo> GetDocumentByName(string Filename)
{
    return db.DocumentsInfo.FromSql("CALL GetDocumentByName({0})", Filename).ToList();
}
```

As you can see I use db - this is dbContext. DocumentsInfo it's my model and I returned a list of DocumentsInfo objects. But what if I don't need to return whole object, but only one column?

Now I need to do the same but with 'Document' but only this time I need to take only one field - DocumentBody, which is BLOB

SQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `GetDocumentBodyById` (DocumentBodyID INT(11))
BEGIN
Select DocumentBody from Document where idDocumentBody = DocumentBodyID;
END$$
```

C#:

```
var test = db.FromSql("CALL GetDocumentBodyById({0})", DocumentID).FirstOrDefault();
```

Gives me an error:

> 'DBContext' does not contain a definition for 'FromSql' and no
>   accessible extension method 'FromSql' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'DBContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or
>   an assembly reference?)

Also tried to use this option:

```
var test = db.Database.SqlQuery<object>("CALL GetDocumentBodyById({0})", DocumentID).FirstOrDefault();
```

But received new error:

> 'DatabaseFacade' does not contain a definition for 'SqlQuery' and no
>   accessible extension method 'SqlQuery'

How to call stored procedure which should return only one value, not whole model object? Is it possible with .net core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `FromSql`, it is used with `Query`, you could define a new model for return result.

```
    public class ResultDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Define `Query` in `OnModelCreating`

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Query<ResultDto>();
    }
```

Useage:

```
  var result = _context.Query<ResultDto>().FromSql("exec GetDocumentBodyById {0}", 1).ToList();
```